Which $n$ will satisfy $\phi(n)=2n$?
The full question says: Perfect numbers satisfy $\sigma(n)=2n$. Which $n$ satisfy $\phi(n)=2n$?
My response is that for $n=p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\dots p_k^{e_k}$, an alternate expression of the $\phi$-function gives
$$\phi(n)=n\left(1-\frac {1} {p_1}\right)\left(1-\frac {1} {p_2}\right)\dots\left(1-\frac {1} {p_k}\right)$$
And this expression suggests that $\phi(n)$ must be less than or equal to $n$, so that there could be NO $n$ (other than one) that would satisfy the condition.
Is my argument sound?

yes, $\phi(n) < n$   unless $n=1$

You don't need the formula. More simply by definition $,\phi(n),$ counts which of the $,\color{#c00}n,$ integers $,1,2,3,\ldots,n,$  are coprime to $,n,,$ so  $,\phi(n)\le \color{#c00}n < 2n.\ \ $

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

@BillDubuque, thank you for your comments. Could you please point me to some place where I can review the purposes of the site so as not to abuse the privilege of using the site? I sought to find a similar question so as not to duplicate an existing question. I am studying by myself, so I have no one that I can ask about these things. So any suggestions are appreciated.

I added the solution-verification tag to your question. If you hover your pointer over it you will see a popup with usage summary. For site quality control see this meta post and its links.

It would be more interesting to consider the equation $\phi(2n)=n$ instead. As it turns out, the solutions to that equation are exactly the powers of $2$.

Mostly, yes.
More precisely, your conclusion is that the formulation of $\phi$ given shows if $n$ has any prime divisors, then $\phi(n) < n$.
But that doesn't mean that, for your final candidate of concern, $\phi(1)=2$. In fact, $\phi(1) = 1$.
So no positive integers whatsoever satisfy $\phi(n)=2n$.

Please do not answer off-topic questions (here a context-lacking SV, as well as surely a dupe).
